# How to set height of horizontal header QHeaderView?

Tags: c++, qt, qheaderview

I need adjust headers of two tables, standing near each other, because headers have different lines of text.
It seems impossible.

Please any help!

Answer (score 2):

Create a class derived from `QHeaderView` and provide your own implementation of `sizeHint` to return the correct height you would like. i.e.

```
QSize MyCustomHeaderView::sizeHint() const
{
    // Get the base implementation size.
    QSize baseSize = QHeaderView::sizeHint();

    // Override the height with a custom value.
    baseSize.setHeight( 25 );

    return baseSize;
}
```